# Select 1 row from table where foreign key table records exist

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables, Products and ProductImages with a one to many relationship between Products and ProductImages.  I'm trying to work a query on on the Products table with a condition that the results contain only rows with matching records in the ProductImages table.

```
Products
----------
id (PK)

ProductImages
---------------
id (PK)
product_id (FK to Products)
```

The only way I can work it is with a subquery, but surely there must be a better/more efficient way.

Comment: which one row? any? smallest ID, biggest ID or what?

Comment: not relevant, really... there are more conditions to the query, but those work just fine, except I'm trying to limit the results to those with records in the productimages table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.* FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN ProductImages AS pi ON p.id = pi.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: I'm curious about this too, being a bit fuzzy on Joins (could never wrap my head around the different ones)

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` is not better than `INNER JOIN` in terms of performance for most cases

Answer (score 2):

user `join`

```
SELECT * FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductImage  on 
Products.id  = ProductImage.product_id
```

Comment: Isn't it `on Products.id  = ProductImages.product_id`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from products
where id in (select product_id from ProductImages)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's precisely the subquery that I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Products.* FROM Products
INNER JOIN ProductImages ON Products.id = ProductImages.id
and Products.Id = @ProductID // if required this condition
```